# How to render a saved component from Map?

Tags: angular

I have a service to save and get a component from Map. And I want to get the saved component from Map and render it in html. But i don't know how. I'm trying to do it with "createComponent", but I'm getting an error that it's not exactly a component. Maybe there is some other way to do this?

Thank you in advance for help

// service for add, get components from the Map

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {
  private componentMap = new Map<string, any>(); // Key: string (component name), Value: component class

  addComponent(name: string, component: any): void {
    this.componentMap.set(name, component);
  }

  getComponent(name: string): any {
    return this.componentMap.get(name);
  }
}
```

// save component in Map

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YourService } from './path-to-your-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css'],
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Add the component to the map when it initializes
    this.yourService.addComponent('yourComponentName', this);
  }
}
```

// render saved component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YourService } from './path-to-your-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another-component',
  template: '<ng-container #dynamicContainer></ng-container>',
})
export class AnotherComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('dynamicContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicContainer!: ViewContainerRef;   

  constructor(
    private yourService: YourService,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const yourComponent = this.yourService.getComponent('yourComponentName');
    
    if(yourComponent) {
      // ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
      this.dynamicContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: “this” is not the component but an instance of a component. Did you try to simply use YourComponent instead of this?

Comment: I know that I can use just a component and it will work, but I need to use an instance. Is it possible to render a component through instance?